# HTACCESS Rewrite if Cookie Present

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

I need a URL rewrite rule for all links if a "mobile" cookie is present.

Our links currently like so:
www.somesite.com/about.html

If this mobile cookie is detected I need all links rewritten www.somesite.com/m/#show/

So basically need /m/#show/ added and then just the page name with not suffix.

Not sure if this is possible but I appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*?mobile=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^about\.html$ /m/#show/ [NC,NE,L,R=302]
```

Comment: Would I need a rule for every page the site has for that to work or is there a way I can use some sort of wildcard for the page name?

Comment: Do you want to redirect every page to `/m/#show/` If yes then use `RewriteRule ^ /m/#show/ [NE,L,R=302]`